# RVM cannot build OpenSSL on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

Ruby will build just fine, but it won't build with OpenSSL support. I've tried setting CC to point to both the XCode 4.6 command line tools' copy of GCC and MacPorts' version of gcc 4.2. That doesn't work. I've added `--with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr` and `--with-opt-dir=$rvm_path/usr`. Neither of those work. Each time it fails, I check the log and it just says that there was an error configuring OpenSSL and that it will be skipped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently after installing `ruby 2.0`, this is how I solved:

```
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm requirements run
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

I found the solution in the comments reported in this [Issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1588)

Answer (score 0):

i was fixing openssl issues while installing ruby on my new shiny mac yesterday.

had to reinstall ruby as @fmendez suggested
but before doing that i had to install openssl . 
i did it through brew.

actually there are lot of other libraries you have to install , like automake , libxslt, etc.

i did ,

`rvm requirements`

it showed me what all to install.please install that first before doing the reinstall of ruby.

also i was facing issues while installing 1.8.4 , for that i had to do

`rvm install 1.18.4--with-gcc=clang --without-tcl --without-tk`

for installing ruby 1.9.2 , i had to do

`rvm install --with-gcc=clang`

hope it helps