# How to install Ruby 2.0.0 on Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

I'm attempting to do a clean install of Ruby 2.0.0 on Lion 10.8.3 with Xcode 4.6.1. I have command line tools installed.

gcc reprots version 4.2.1
git, sqlite3, etc. are all installed.

I'm trying to do a clean install. I did the following steps

1. rvm uninstall all
2. rvm implode

Then the new install

1. curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable  # to install rvm
2. rvm requirements

I get the following response from rvm requirements.

> ## For ruby:
>
> Install: osx-gcc-installer libksba openssl libreadline git zlib1g libyaml libsqlite3 sqlite3 libxml2 libxslt autoconf libc6 libgdbm ncurses automake libtool bison pkg-config

What is this telling me to do? How do I install all these packages?

gcc reports version 4.2.1
git, sqlite3, etc. are all installed.

If I attempt install despite it, it eventually fails.

I do iOS development as well and can't afford to disrupt my Xcode environment.

For security reasons, as a general policy I am running under a non-admin userid. My intent in using rvm was to keep the changes local to my userid, yet other tools such as homebrew seem to require at least admin access if not sudo.

Comment: Follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479418/rvm-cannot-build-openssl-on-mountain-lion/15479800#15479800

Comment: also, after running the `rvm requirements run` install any of the `formulas` hinted by `homebrew`

Answer (score 0):

Use Homebrew to install stuff like you would with apt-get (or similar PM's) on Linux.

[Link](https://brew.sh)

For the plain Ruby part: There is an *official* GUI Tool to handle RVM for you:

http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/

I just installed Ruby 2.0 with 2 clicks. Depending on your XCode, Ruby Versions < 1.9p125 could be more problematic, though.

Comment: Seems like a fragile environment. I tried latest jewerlybox. Go to add Ruby, presents dialog, tell it to do it, flashes that its searching for binaries, goes to a blank panel. Dead from there.

Comment: mostly, this has sth to do with your version of XCode and if or not having GCC installed, and which ruby version you want. On my week-old MBP with 10.8, newest xcode and jewelrybox, 2.0 installs without problems. see http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/#!faq the last bullet for what i mean.

Comment: Ok. I thought I had Xcode command line tools installed but I didn't. Jewelrybox worked to install ruby 2.0. However when I try to install Rails it still fails with 'cannot load such file -- openssl'.

Comment: try `brew install openssl`